# Wrong commit order when using autoCommit=false in HighlevelConsumer

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, autocommit

I'm using a HighlevelProducer and HighlevelConsumer to send and receive Messages. The HighlevelConsumer is configured with autoCommit=false as I want to commit Messages only when it was produced successfully. The problem is, that the first message never really gets commited.

Example:

- Send Messages 1-10.
- Receive Message 1
- Receive Message 2
- Commit Message 2
- ...
- Receive Message 10
- Commit Message 10
- Commit Message 1

If I restart my Consumer, all messages from 1 to 10 are processed again. Only if I send new messages to the consumer, the old messages get committed. This happens for any number of messages.

My Code reads as follows:

```js
var kafka = require('kafka-node'),
    HighLevelConsumer = kafka.HighLevelConsumer,
    client = new kafka.Client("localhost:2181/");
consumer = new HighLevelConsumer(
    client,
    [
        { topic: 'mytopic' }
    ],
    {
        groupId: 'my-group',
        id: "my-consumer-1",
        autoCommit: false
    }
);

consumer.on('message', function (message) {
    console.log("consume: " + message.offset);
    consumer.commit(function (err, data) {
        console.log("commited:" + message.offset);
    });
    console.log("consumed:" + message.offset);
});

process.on('SIGINT', function () {
    consumer.close(true, function () {
        process.exit();
    });
});

process.on('exit', function () {
    consumer.close(true, function () {
        process.exit();
    });
});
```

```js
var messages = 10;
var kafka = require('kafka-node'),
    HighLevelProducer = kafka.HighLevelProducer,
    client = new kafka.Client("localhost:2181/");
var producer = new HighLevelProducer(client, { partitionerType: 2, requireAcks: 1 });

producer.on('error', function (err) { console.log(err) });
producer.on('ready', function () {
    for (i = 0; i < messages; i++) {
        payloads = [{ topic: 'mytopic', messages: "" }];
        producer.send(payloads, function (err, data) {
            err ? console.log(i + "err", err) : console.log(i + "data", data);
        });
    }
});
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in kafka-node?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why commitAsync fails to commit the first 2 offsets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37794718/why-commitasync-fails-to-commit-the-first-2-offsets)

Answer (score 0):

A commit of message 2 is an implicit commit of message 1.

As you commits are done asynchronously, and commit of message 1 and message 2 are done quick after each other (ie, committing 2 happens before the consumer did send the commit of 1), the first commit will not happen explicitly and only a single commit of message 2 will be sent.